# Singleton JS Object in Angular Service

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add methods to an Object's protoype, which will be used in a singleton service and will be initiated only once when the service is created.

```
angular
        .module('app.steps')
        .factory('stepsService', stepsService);

    stepsService.$inject = [];

    /* @ngInject */
    function stepsService() {
        var steps = new Steps(1,3);

    function Steps(current_step, total_steps) {
        this.c_step = current_step;
        this.t_step = total_steps;            
    }

    Steps.prototype = {
        addSteps: function (num) {
            this.c_step += num;
        },
        setLastStep: function () {
            this.lastStep = this.c_step = this.t_step;
        }
    };

    var service = {
        steps: steps           
    };       

    return service; 
    }
```

My problem is that although the object is created and initiated successfully, the methods are not there.
What is missing?

Comment: Move `var steps = new Steps(1,3);` after `Steps.prototype = {....}`

Comment: You need to create the object `var steps = new Steps(1,3);` after `Steps.prototype={...}`

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248759/singleton-js-object-in-angular-service#comment62026022_37248759), `var steps = new Steps(1,3);` should be after `Steps.prototype = {....}`